# spinner inside listview custom row layout and Adapters

Tags: android, spinner, android-arrayadapter, baseadapter

I followed almost all the threads about this and didn't find an answer (if there is one..).
I have app which is table of values and to each value i have spinner for the user to choose.
I implemented it by listview (can also with gridview with 1 column), with custom layout (`linearLayout` with 2 `textViews` for the ID and `VALUE_TEXT` and `Spinner`).
the Spinner is with custom layout also - value Id in the spinner and the text.
the both IDs (`ListView` value ID and Spinner value ID is hidden from the user and it is for my use).
i have few questions about my implementation :

1) is that the best way to implement rows in UI (`ListView` and `Spinners`) when you need to save its ID? i am getting the data from `Json`, which gets me the ListView items (ID and TEXT), and for each spinner i am getting (after POSTing the value ID to the server) the values for the spinner and their ID. i am communicating with the server only with the IDs, so i have to save them somewhere..

2) is there a way to get the ListView row (for getting its ID) from the `Spinner OnItemSelected` method? i have only the parent parameter, which is `AdapterView`.

3) Now i am extending `BaseAdapter` (one for the ListView and one for the Spinner) in order to be able to populate the data in the UI. i am using its getView method to inflate the custom layout and putting the data to it? isn't there a simpler way with ArrayAdapter to perform such action?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ListActivity since it gives you a lot of shortcut methods to make things easier and keep your code more readable.

For example, you get the onListItemClick() method which is called whenever you click a item which saves you from creating a separate listener.

If you want to change the layout of a ListActivity you still can with setContentView() method from Activity. As long as there is a ListView called @android:id/list somewhere in your View the ListActivity will still work.

Comment: i understand it and you are right. the only issue is with the layout - i need spinner in each row, so i still needs custom layout and adapter for it, no? also - how can the ListActivity help me with the spinner selection - i need to perform action with both spinner ID selected and the list row id which the spinner lays inside it (for example, the third row in the list had ID [which is external ID, not the ListView row ID] of 7, and i choose in the spinner the second option, which has ID 9, i need to perform POST to the server with both IDs to get the proper answer..)